# Flexbox support in Phantomjs to use in html2ng node.js

Tags: css, node.js, phantomjs, flexbox

I am trying to take a screen shot of website using node.js module `html2png` which uses [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) version 1.9. I read it somewhere that this version of phantomjs does not support flexbox property of css. Can anyone please let me how to support flexbox property in phantomjs. or any work around.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest 2.5beta: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads

You probably could swap the old binary for the new one.

Comment: I want to use this in html2png module of node.js swapping the binary will work ?